# insert data to database via java swing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try
    {           
        String rID=rid.getText();
        String cID=cid.getText();
        double Rcharge=Double.parseDouble(rc.getText());
        double Mcharge=Double.parseDouble(mc.getText());
        double total=Double.parseDouble(tot.getText());
        double sum=Double.parseDouble(cash.getText());
        double change=Double.parseDouble(bal.getText());

        if(c_but.isSelected())
        {
                String sql ="INSERT INTO transactions(reservation_id,cus_id,room_charges,meal_charges,total_amount,cash,balance,payment_type) VALUES ('"+rID+"','"+cID+"','"+Rcharge+"','"+Mcharge+"','"+total+"','"+sum+"','"+change+"','CASH')" ;
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.execute();

       }
        else if(cre_but.isSelected())
        {
               String sql2 ="INSERT INTO transactions(reservation_id,cus_id,room_charges,meal_charges,total_amount,payment_type) VALUES ('"+rID+"','"+cID+"','"+Rcharge+"','"+Mcharge+"','"+total+"','CRED')" ;
               pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
               pst.execute();           
        }           
}   
catch(Exception e){           
}
```

I create above code to insert data into mysql database.
`c_but` and `cre_but` are radio buttons.
There are no syntax errors.
But the values that i'm adding from interface aren't going to table.Can any one find the error please?

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions. You should print them, log them or handle them, not ignore them like you're doing with an empty catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some exception is thrown, but it's not visible becase of empty catch-block, so it behaves as the program succesfully completes.
Rewrite catch-block like that:

```
catch(Exception e){
    throw e;     
}
```

And you might see what the problem is.

Comment: If you want to 'rethrow' you could just as well not add the catch clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code doesn't tell you much if anything goes wrong.

I suggest you:

- Add error logging or `throw new RuntimeError(e)` to the catch block
- Throw an error or add a debug log (depending on your application's logic) if neither of the conditions (`c_but` or `cre_but`) is met

If you don't find or understand the error based on the additional info you get, you may edit the question with these additional details. Without it, it is improbable anyone will be able to help you.

---

On an unrelated note, I strongly suggest you read something on [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).